# Проверка куки на сообщение по вебсокету

Tags: java, http, java-ee, websocket

Могу ли я получить данные кук через вебсокет?

Попытался в `onMessage` получить `session.getUpgradeRequest().getCookies()`, выдает `null`, хотя куки есть в браузере.

Как лучше всего на каждое сообщение на вебсокет с клиента проверять наличие куки?

Как простейший вариант, могу с клиента к каждому сообщению на сервер добавлять данные кук, но будет ли это оптимально?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать localStorage?

Comment: @gil9red можно. Вопрос все тот же, как лучше получить эти данные на сервере?

Comment: если данных не много (UUID например) -- можно и в каждом